# HTML Entities em PHP e Java

Tags: php, java, html, android

Estou usando *htmlentities()*
no PHP para armazenar dados no banco de dados, substituindo **ç**, **ã**, e outros caracteres por entidades HTML:

```
<?PHP
htmlentities ("Ampliação");
//Resulta na string "Amplia&ccedil;&atilde;o
```

No Java (Android) preciso decodificar essas entidades para seus respectivos valores de origem ("Ampliação"), porém não achei uma solução eficaz, apenas a função

> *StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(String)*

mas ela está convertendo para caracteres diferentes dos originais, além de estar depreciada.

O método

> URLDecoder.decoder(String)

Também não resultou na string original.

Alguma dica?

Comment: Porque armazenar a string fazendo a subtituição? Não poderia guardar a string original e quando precisasse exibir em uma página html faria a conversão usado htmlentities()?

Comment: Depois de horas tentando configurar o banco de dados para aceitar caracteres especiais eu desisti, tentei de tudo. O PHP tá configurado pra UTF-8, no BD tentei UTF-8, Latin1, de todos os tipos e nada funcionou

Comment: Também aceito resposta pra configurar o banco de dados, ao invés de fazer a substituição dos caracteres

Comment: Nesse caso é melhor criar outra pergunta, já que outros procurando respostas para a mesma questão vão se basear pelo título. Nessa pergunta inclua o máximo de informações: como você está salvando no banco (código), qual o banco de dados, o que aparece quando você olha os registros no banco (e.g. uma consulta sql direto no BD e não via aplicação), qual o "nada funcionou" exatamente, e o que mais você imaginar que possa ajudar alguém a te ajudar ;-)

Comment: Ja tentou usar `Html.fromHtml((String) htmlCode).toString()` ?

Comment: @acklay, funcionou! Era exatamente isso.

Comment: Só não precisa do casting dentro do fromHtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o método [Html.fromHtml()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml(java.lang.String,%20int,%20android.text.Html.ImageGetter,%20android.text.Html.TagHandler)). Veja abaixo um exemplo:

```
String value =  Html.fromHtml(sua_string).toString();
```

Para mais detalhes veja [aqui da documentação](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html).